# What is the power boost I get in low gear high RPM

Tags: nissan, power, micra

I recently upgraded to a Nissan Micra Vibe 1.2 2015 Petrol from a 2005 Petrol C4.

Something different I notice when driving in low gear (1-3) high RPM (3000+) is without changing the amount of gas I supply or anything else, the car suddenly gets a significant boost in power and pulls me into the seat to accelerate more.

Am I imagining it or is there something more going that I'm missing ?

Comment: The turbo coming into boost as the revs increase?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't think there's a Turbo in the car to be completely honest ...

Comment: Is it a "DIG-S"? Because if so, then it has a supercharger that comes in above a certain speed and load or accelerator setting which will give the same  effect...

Comment: @SolarMike It seams the DIG-S is the Tekna Trim, mine is the Vibe http://www.parkers.co.uk/nissan/micra/hatchback-2010/12-vibe-5d/specs/ I'll double check against the VIN and would eyeball for a Turbo again, in an hour.

Comment: so 2015 as per your question or 2010 as per the info you now provide ?? As per the link - was the DIG-S specified when the vehicle was purchased as it may have been an option ... If you have air-con then that usually means the higher spec engine - based on the "blurb" in the link you provided.

Comment: @SolarMike I got the car a month ago from a used car dealer. It has an AC  but that's basically the second to cheapest model they offer. Better versions have Cruise Control speed limiter etc. mine is basically limited to AC. Also if you click the link you get "Available new from: November 2015  -  November 2016" which fits mine's description. I never heard the dearer, saw in the listing or the documents anything mentioning DIG-S.

Comment: Assuming the car is accelerating under the noted conditions it may be coming into an RPM at which the tuning of the intake and/or exhaust enhances the normal induction fuel charge.  This result from the high pressure acoustic waves providing a denser fuel charge.